# Why was Comirnaty (Pfizer's COVID vaccine) FDA approval only for ages 16+, and not 12+? Will it be expanded to 12+?

Tags: covid-19

From https://www.fda.gov/news-events/press-announcements/fda-approves-first-covid-19-vaccine:

> For Immediate Release: August 23, 2021

> Today, the U.S. Food and Drug
> Administration approved the first COVID-19 vaccine. The vaccine has
> been known as the Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 Vaccine, and will now be
> marketed as Comirnaty (koe-mir’-na-tee), for the prevention of
> COVID-19 disease in individuals 16 years of age and older. The vaccine
> also continues to be available under emergency use authorization
> (EUA), including for individuals 12 through 15 years of age and for
> the administration of a third dose in certain immunocompromised
> individuals.

After the FDA approval of Pfizer's COVID vaccine, I have started to hear COVID vaccine misinformation that the "age for the Pfizer vaccine was raised from 12 back to 16", with the implication that it was unsafe for under 16. This is clearly not true, as the FDA states above that it continues to be available under emergency use authorization for individuals 12 through 15 years of age. However, it does raise the following questions:

1. What is the specific documented reason (or specific documented
   reasons) that the Comirnaty vaccine was approved only for
   "individuals 16 years of age and older", while ages 12-15 are still
   only under the EUA?
2. Will the FDA approval be expanded to individuals 12 years of age and older?

I feel I need to address one part of the FDA news release, as I do not believe it specifically answers my question (emphasis added):

> Additionally, the FDA conducted a rigorous evaluation of the
> post-authorization safety surveillance data pertaining to myocarditis
> and pericarditis following administration of the Pfizer-BioNTech
> COVID-19 Vaccine and has determined that the data demonstrate
> increased risks, particularly within the seven days following the
> second dose. The observed risk is higher among males under 40 years of
> age compared to females and older males. **The observed risk is highest
> in males 12 through 17 years of age.** Available data from short-term
> follow-up suggest that most individuals have had resolution of
> symptoms. However, some individuals required intensive care support.
> Information is not yet available about potential long-term health
> outcomes. The Comirnaty Prescribing Information includes a warning
> about these risks.

It mentions "12 through 17 years of age" instead of "12 through 15". It seems reasonable to me that because "the risk is highest in males 12 through 17 years of age", that if that were the reason for going with 16+ instead of 12+, that the approval would have been for 18+ instead of 16+ (or possibly different age ranges for males and females). Regardless, that section of the news release is not specifically stating the reason for 16+, so I don't consider it to be an answer to my question.

IMPORTANT: Any valid answers must be accompanied by relevant quotes from trusted and credible sources that specifically answer the question. All sources must be available via the open web, without requiring signups or payment to access. Quotes from sources must contain full context and not be altered (definitely no "...", no "[]", etc). If any emphasis is added, it must be noted. If any answer is given that doesn't comply with the above requirements, it should be treated with extreme skepticism.

Comment: May I point out that you ask multiple questions in a single posting which is nor really part of the stack exchange model. Also, we already have the source requirements as part of our charter, adding that is unnecessary and comes across as a bit rude and demanding, which may be why you are receiving downvotes. Simply ask the question and it may be better received.

Answer (score 5):

The way FDA approval works is that a manufacturer submits an application to the FDA for something they want to produce and market; FDA decides whether to approve or deny that application based on its contents.

From [Pfizer and BioNTech's press release](https://investors.biontech.de/news-releases/news-release-details/pfizer-and-biontech-initiate-rolling-submission-biologics), dated May 7th, 2021:

> Pfizer Inc. (NYSE: PFE) and BioNTech SE (Nasdaq: BNTX) today announced the initiation of a Biologics License Application (BLA) with the U.S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA) for approval of their mRNA vaccine to prevent COVID-19 in individuals 16 years of age and older

From this we can infer that the application submitted for Comirnaty was for individuals 16+, so that's what FDA approved. We can infer that they did **not** ask for approval for anyone else, otherwise they would have announced it. They indicate this will happen once they have sufficient data:

> Pfizer and BioNTech also have submitted an application to expand the current EUA for their COVID-19 vaccine to include individuals 12 to 15 years of age. The Companies intend to submit a supplemental BLA to support licensure of the vaccine in this age group once the required data 6 months after the second vaccine dose are available.

Presumably this is because trials started first in adults and older children so there were more data towards full approval in those groups, whereas data for younger children were collected more recently. The FDA only recently [expanded the EUA to kids 12+ on May 10th](https://www.fda.gov/media/148542/download), just 3 days after they announced their application for full approval.